I'm trying to use a different link in Netlify Visual Editor, projects section
I’m trying to create my own portfolio on netlify

https://luccarosa.netlify.app/
https://github.com/scriptedgrain/my-portfolio

I’m using the template Portfolio site with visual editing
So, in the button below any project, I wish there was an option to add an external link to these buttons instead a new page for every new project in my website. How could I do to change the code or inside the Netlify Create tool to add external links to these buttons? Because I wanted to link my repositories instead a new page from each new project.
I hope someone can help me!
